# How to set a multiple values type input variables for a Flow in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I have a flow with an input variables which set allow multiple values. Please see follow image:

[image]

In Process Builder, I want set 'targets' values like ["Prospect","Other"], may I ask how to do this, and is here any document in Salesforce tell how to set a multiple value in Flow at Process Builder?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the multiple values are intended for a multipicklist, you can See Daniel Howell’s 2017 comment https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D0vEAAS

Basically “yes”, you can use process builder to write “Value1;Value2;Value3”  and so on.

The semi-colon denotes distinct multipicklist entries

Comment: Thanks for you share information, I test in my org, this only works on MultipickList Field. As for multiple input variables looks like in process builder it only support single value.

Comment: btw similar to running  flows from process builder,  you could also consider running invocable apex from process builder.  Thats one way to pass a collection from pB to some logic.